# Connecting to your own PC using telnet and Server Sockets. Get connection rejected each time

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I've pasted my whole code below, the majority of it is not related to the issue. I'm trying to create a Java server and then use telnet to connect to it (on the same PC) and put out random strings. So far, I cannot get past the face that I get my connection rejected every time I telnet to my PC. I successfully managed to connect to my university computers whilst in class but not at home, for some reason.

I've listed the code below. Are there ports that I should open or could it be an issue with Windows 10 or something? I'm really new to Sockets thus I don't really know what I'm talking about myself.

```
package cm3033.lab3.ex1nonthreadedechoserver;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainAppEx1NonThreadedEchoServer 
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    try 
    { 
      ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8189) ; 
      // listen for a connection request on server socket s
      // incoming is the connection socket
      for(;;)
      { 
        Socket incoming = s.accept() ; 
        // set up streams for bidirectional transfer
        // across connection socket 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader 
          (new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream())) ; 
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter 
          (incoming.getOutputStream(), true /* auto flush */) ; 
        out.println("You are connected to " + 
          incoming.getLocalAddress().getHostName() + 
          " on port " + incoming.getLocalPort() 
        ) ; 
        out.println("Type BYE to quit") ; 
        boolean done = false ; 
        while(!done) 
        { 
          String str = in.readLine() ; 
          if (str == null) 
            done = true ; 
          else 
          { 
            out.println("ECHO: " + str) ; 
            if (str.trim().equals("BYE")) 
              done = true ; 
          } 
        } 
        incoming.close() ;
      } 
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    { 
      System.out.println(e) ; 
    } 
  } 
}</code>
```

The image below is the message I get when I try to telnet.

[image: telnet error]

Comment: You get 'connection refused' or 'connect timeout'. Not 'connection rejected'. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do a telnet without giving the port number so it defaults to 23. However you have set up your server with port 8189.

Use `telnet s-PC 8189` instead.

Comment: Oh my god, that's so simple yet I'm so stupid... This works. Thanks a lot :)